# Using regex compile through loop in Python

Tags: python, regex, loops

I have a text  which I want to match through words in a given set.
After matching it will simply tag them.
The code is this

```
mytext = "xxxxx repA1 yyyy REPA1 zzz."
geneset = {'leuB', 'repA1'} # The actual length is ~1Million entries

result = mytext
for gene in geneset:
    regexp = re.compile(gene, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    result = re.sub(regexp, r'<GENE>\g<0></GENE>', mytext)

print result
```

The expected output is:

```
xxxxx <GENE>repA1</GENE> yyyy <GENE>REPA1</GENE> zzz.
```

But why the code above failed to generate the results?

Comment: [Your code seems to work for me.](http://codepad.org/ifcsb8pw) Apart from the change from a set to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are using the `re.sub` over the original text (that no are changing in each loop), if you use instead the result variable like `result = re.sub(regexp, r'<GENE>\g<0></GENE>', result)` the output will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `mytext` in `re.sub` to `result`. That way you update the variable `result` each time you loop over `geneset`, instead of starting with the original (and not-updated) string `mytext` on every iteration.

```
for gene in geneset:
    regexp = re.compile(r"(?i)({})".format(gene))
    result = re.sub(regexp, r'<GENE>\g<1></GENE>', result)
```